# Append the parent selector to the end with Sass

Tags: sass

Ok, suppose I have the following traditional CSS

```
.social-media { /* ... */ }
.social-media .twitter { /* ... */ }
.social-media .facebook { /* ... */ }
ul.social-media { /* ... */ }
```

So, I tried to do it like this with SCSS:

```
.social-media {

    /* ... */

    .twitter { 
        /* ... */
    }
    .facebook {
        /* ... */
    }

    // Here's the problem:
    ul& {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The last part does not work, because it seems like the ampersand should only appear at the beginning of a selector. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You need to consider rethinking the way you're naming things. Why do you have an element with the class `social-media`, and then an unordered list inside of it with the same class name?

Comment: @zakang you didn't understand it properly. I have some styles defined to .social-media elements, in general. And then, I want to apply some particular styles to the UL elements with the `.social-media` class. There's nothing like `.social-media ul.social-media` in my code, like you're implying.

Comment: My fault, too much code scanning and not enough reading :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Sass 3.2 and older

The only thing you can do is reverse your nesting or not nest at all:
    .social-media {

```
    /* ... */

    .twitter { 
        /* ... */
    }
    .facebook {
        /* ... */
    }
}

ul.social-media {
    /* ... */
}
```

## Sass 3.3 and later

You can do that using interpolation and the `@at-root` directive:

```
.social-media {
    /* ... */

    // Here's the solution:
    @at-root ul#{&} {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

However, if your parent selector contains multiple selectors, you'll need to use `selector-append` instead:

```
.social-media, .doodads {
    /* ... */

    // Here's the solution:
    @at-root #{selector-append(ul, &)} {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.social-media, .doodads {
  /* ... */
}
ul.social-media, ul.doodads {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Incredibly you can darken and lighten colors from your sass and you cannot do something like this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It has to do with the fact that using `&` is not simple string replacement.  If your parent selector had been `ul.foo`, you might have ended up with `ulul.foo` if that were the case.

Comment: hm... this solution works fine on sassmeister, but on my local, with same version of sass as sassmeister, this gives me an error :(

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu Check your dependencies.  If you have the correct version, you likely have a library that depends on an older version.  The `sass --version` command will only report the newest version you have installed, rather than all versions.

Comment: @cimmanon, you are right, I have an older version of compass that depends on sass o~> 3.3.0.rc.1 so.... not sure if I'll be able to upgrade for that. Thank for the answer!