# Sass: Adding variable suffix to all selectors in a DRY way

Tags: sass

I'm putting together a style framework for the sake of familiarizing myself with sass and building out interfaces quicker. Needless to say, I am not that great with sass. Any criticism is welcome.

There are plenty of frameworks out there, but you commonly see selectors prefixed with some string unique to whatever style framework you're using.
(e.g. UI Kit prefixes all their classes with 'uk-' http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html ).

I'm planning to use other prefixes for utility clases (.u-), typography classes (.text-), and so on. So using a prefix that signifies "hey this class is from this style framework" would make code horribly unreadable.

So something like:

```
$prefix: uk-;

.#{$prefix} {

    &u-truncateText { 
        display: inline-block;
    }

    // Other utility selectors
}
```

Unfortunately, gets you something like:

```
.uk-u-truncateText { ... }
```

When ideally, we want something like:

```
.u-truncateText--uk { ... }
```

This, in my opinion, is nice because:

1. It's more legible.
2. It kind-of-sorf-of follows the component--modifier structure you see in a lot of style frameworks. (e.g. "This is not a .container; this is a .container--myFramework")
3. If you're working in an existing web software with their own generic classes, it's readily apparent what classes are yours or not. That's useful when making a home, about, or contact page in a forum software, for example.

While you could append #{$prefix}, ( or in this case #{$suffix} ) to every selector. The anguish of typing that for every single selector will likely drive you mad.

Any possible ways in which this can be achieved in a DRY way? Thanks, all!

Comment: What you have is already as short as you're going to get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append the parent selector to the end with Sass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$suffix: --uk;

#{$suffix} {

    @at-root {
        .u-truncateText#{&} {
           display: inline-block;
        }

    // Other utility selectors
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
.u-truncateText--uk {
  display: inline-block; }
```

> From what I understand, you can't use the & at the end of a string, only at > the beginning.

See also: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1612 and http://sass-compatibility.github.io/#ampersand_sassscript, so you can use `.u-truncateText#{&}` or alternatively `#{selector-append('.u-truncateText',&)}`