# SASS mixin - hot to limit to a certain type of tag?

Tags: sass, mixins

```
@mixin foobar(){
  outline: 1px solid red;
  td#{&}{
    outline: 1px solid blue;
  }
}

.foo{
  @include foobar;
}
```

outputs :

```
.foo {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.foo td.foo {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I would like to output :

```
.foo {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

td.foo {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

how can it be achieved ? I played with "@at-root" but it doesn't seem to be meant to do that.

Comment: Whoops, linked to the wrong duplicate, here's the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass

Comment: yes @cimmanon it seems to be the right answer

Comment: SO cimmanon posted the link to the "right" answer to the question. But that "right" answer isn't really reliable and fails in many cases therefore sobolevn answers are imo a better choice.

Comment: Except you haven't presented a case where it "fails".

Comment: the solution presented is very interesting, but it relies on the element type being present in the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two ways here. The complex one:

```
@mixin foobar($class, $tags...) {
  @each $tag in $tags {
    $selector: $tag + $class;
    @at-root #{$selector} {
      outline: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
}

.bar {
  @include foobar(&, 'tr', 'td');
}
```

Output:

```
tr.bar { outline: 1px solid blue; }
td.bar { outline: 1px solid blue; }
```

And the easy one:

```
%abs_foo {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.foo {
  @at-root td#{&} {
    @extend %abs_foo;
  }

  @extend %abs_foo;
}
```

With the output:

```
.foo, td.foo { outline: 1px solid blue; }
```

I have created a gist for you: http://sassmeister.com/gist/361cd515562035b0ffa7

Comment: thanks for help. I am not sure how to use your two suggestions, since the mixin is already existing and implemented in many places. I want to extend it, by having specific rules for certain tag types.

Comment: You can add `@if`. I have updated my gist: http://sassmeister.com/gist/0c13513cb540d8c2f0ba

Comment: but this is relying on the mixins param, which is not an option, since there is alreays many implementations. I simplified the gist without the pramas, but then it is not working : http://sassmeister.com/gist/3c43869d57050a61ca83

Comment: In this case use: `@if str-index(#{&}, 'span') == 1 {} @else {}`. But why you just can't write new mixin?

Comment: when used on a td the mixin fails, it needs position: relative, but only when it is a td. Therefore I dont want a new mixins, I want to fix thisone in order to fix all occurrences of the bug.