# Target Parent and Some other selector

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to try and target the parent selector, plus also append some other selector to it.

What I want is

```
.first .second {
  display: none;
}

.first.show .second {
  display: block;
}
```

I have tried:

```
.first {
    .second {
        display: none;
        .show& {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

as well as some others.  That one seems most logical to me, but apparently you can't have an ampersand directly after a selector.

Any advice?

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass

Answer (score 1):

use

```
.first {
    .second {
        display: none;

    }
    &.show .second {
            display: block;
        }
}
```

Reference: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector