# How can I append a parent using SASS without a space?

Tags: sass

I want to append a parent selector using an ampersand, but without a space between the two. How would I do this?

Input:

```
[disabled], [readonly]{
  .form-control &, &.wpcf7-form-control[type="text"]{
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
}
```

Current Output has a space after "form-control" :

```
.form-control [disabled], [disabled].wpcf7-form-control[type="text"], .form-control [readonly], [readonly].wpcf7-form-control[type="text"]{
  cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

Desired Output does not have a space after "form-control":

```
.form-control[disabled], [disabled].wpcf7-form-control[type="text"], .form-control[readonly], [readonly].wpcf7-form-control[type="text"]{
  cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: This answered my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass?rq=1

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass?rq=1