# SASS: Trailing ampersand (closely attached) does not combine with every parent selector separated by comma

Tags: sass

I am having trouble with Sass 3.4. I am using trailing ampersand to select all parent selectors separated by commas but am having issues. Only the first parent selector is attached and not the rest. Here is code:

**SASS code**

```
.shopify {
    .content a, .sidebar a { // IMPORTANT: Note the two selectors seperated by comma
        @each $skin, $value in $skins {
            $foo: &;
            @at-root .#{$skin}#{$foo} {
                color: map-get($value, 'link-color');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
.green-skin.shopify .content a, .green-skin .shopify .sidebar a { color: #60bc4b }
```

NOTE: the `.green-skin` is **attached closely** with `.shopify` only in the FIRST selector. In the second selector, they are not connected.

**Expected output**

```
.green-skin.shopify .content a, .green-skin.shopify .sidebar a { color: #60bc4b }
```

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108158/413793).

Had to replace the @at-root part with this

```
@at-root .#{selector-append($skin, &)} {
    color: map-get($value, 'accent-color');
}
```