# scss continue name with interpolation and `@at-root`

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to fully understand the ampersand (&) and [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) operators in `sass`, while also following [bem](http://getbem.com/naming/). For example, I have a `table` block declared like so:

```
.table {
  width: 60%;
  &__title {
    // omit code
  }
  &__data {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    & > #{@at-root}__key + #{@at-root}__value > * { // <- ISSUE HERE
      // give all direct, non text child nodes margin below
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
  }
}
```

and used like:

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table__title'>...</div>
  <div class='table__data'>
    <div class='table__key'>...</div>
    <div class='table__value'>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See line 9 of the sass; here the expected compiled result would be

```
.table__data > .table__key + .table__value > * {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

but of course `@at-root` is not a variable so an error is thrown

> SassError: Invalid CSS after "@": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@at-root}__key + #{"

Does anything like my attempt exist, can/**should** I somehow combine the `@at-root` element with classes I'm using?

Articles I've already tried:

- [Append the parent selector to the end with Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass)

**EDIT** made the question clearer

Comment: Can you edit your question with the compiled CSS you're trying to achieve? Not totally clear what the issue is with the SASS you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do when I actually deem this necessary is to just create your reference from the root. It's kind of like the old days when you often had to declare `that = this` scenarios (well not really but you get the idea lol).

However, generally I avoid this kind of deep nesting unless it's genuinely required to avoid too many levels of specificity (habit from the old days when such noticeably things [effected performance](https://medium.com/developer-rants/the-problem-1f121f6aecbf).

See example below, and a [codepen to tinker](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/RwVNRZg)

```
.table {
  $root: &; // <-- create reference to root that allows interpolation.
  width: 60%;
  &__title {
    // omit code
  }
  &__data {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    & > #{$root}__key + #{$root}__value > * { // <- ISSUE HERE
      // give all direct, non text child nodes margin below
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
  }
}
```

...and the compiled output...

```
.table {
  width: 60%;
}
.table__data {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}
.table__data > .table__key + .table__value > * {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because this is the exact same compiled output as what OP already has in their question that is apparently problematic.

Comment: @cjl750 sorry to ask man, but did you even read the question? PS - Rock Chalk! ;)

Comment: Yeah I read the question, but since your code compiles to the same thing as what OP already has and you also haven't incorporated `@at-root` anywhere (in the event that what OP wants is to literally use that specific syntax for whatever reason), I don't see how this answer is helpful. It's clever, but it doesn't accomplish anything new. Maybe I'm not understanding the intent of the question, but that is why I asked OP to update the question with the desired output.

Comment: @cjl750 Try running the portion where he says "here I want to do something like.." .... because it's invalid and will break compilation, hence why he asked "Does anything like my attempt exist...", right? Sounds like you're just putting his first example in and that's how you're seeing the same output because if you introduce the part he is actually trying to do, well it would not and `@at-root` is not for what he's trying. Cheers 

Comment: @cjl750 this answer is accepted because it does answer my (OP's) question - all I wanted was a workaround, this answer was just perfect :)

Comment: @warren thanks for the update. If this answer answers your question, then I find your question very confusing, but glad it works for you. I would be happy to reverse my vote, but I can't do that unless you edit your question. Maybe you could edit it to explain the underlying problem you're trying to solve: why is this answer even necessary if it produces the same output as what you already had?

Comment: @cjl750 thanks for pointing that out, I edited it to make my intent, as well as the error, clearer

Comment: Kind of cool trick with variable, that's the way to work around SASS's current stupid limitations. Hope they loosen those one day... Thanks @ChrisW.